# How to copy-paste the whole discover page to my Kibana dashboard?

Tags: kibana

I'm using Kibana 5. I want to copy-paste the whole discover page content (including the plot and fields filters) to my dashboard:

[image]

In order to do that I save a search and then insert it into the dashboard. Unfortunately, I get only the list of requests without fields filter and plot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's how it is. You can save the search with the desired filters if you want by selecting them on the discover page before saving, but that's about it as far as I know :)

As for the graph, i think you're gonna have to make the visualisation yourself, which is fairly simple: its a vertical bar chart, with count on the y-axis and date histogram on the x-axis I believe.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Anna! Yep, I did a graph myself, but unfortunately, you can't select time window on it, as you do it in Discover mode. I tried to use Timelion graph instead, but have some issues with filtering the request. Oh well =)

Comment: If the time range on the dashboard doesn't help and you want to go with the Timelion approach, I suggest that you make a post on https://discuss.elastic.co/, it's an active community and they have dedicated elasticsearch members that might be able to help you build your Timelion expression :)

Comment: Anna, I managed to get Timelion visualization work, so we're more or less ok for now. Thanks for your help!